# Помогите разобраться в отношениях таблиц в Angular 10

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, angular10

Я пытаюсь завести фронтенд от angular с беком от Django Rest, настраиваю эндпоинты и логику.
В наличии имеется готовое решение фронта на angular, авторизацию я уже сделал, по крайней мере она происходит (но почему то при рефреше страницы сбрасывается, почему?)
У меня имеется директория mocks, в которой содержатся модели объектов, используемых в angular (не знаю как правильно описать).
Названия у самих файлов  XXXXX.models.ts
Пример содержимого:

```
import {Compound} from "./compound.model";
import {Metadata} from "./metadata.model";
import {Score} from "./score.model";
import {Tag} from "./tag.model";
import {Submitter} from "./submitter.model";
import {Splash} from "./splash.model";
import {Library} from "./library.model";

export class SpectrumModel {
  compound: Compound[];
  id: string;
  metaData: Metadata[];
  annotations: Metadata[];
  score: Score;
  spectrum: string;
  lastUpdated: string;
  dateCreated: string;
  lastCurated: string;
  splash: Splash;
  submitter: Submitter;
  tags: Tag[];
  library: Library;
  similarity: number;
  metaDataMap:{};
}
```

Помогите понять, какие отношения с таблицами, указанными в этой модели?
Например:

```
metaData: Metadata[];
submitter: Submitter;
metaDataMap:{};
```

- Я предполагаю, что для metaData подразумевается отношение один ко многим ForeigKey, т.е. множество объектов модели Metadata может относится к модели Spectrum? (я предполагаю это видя скобки []).
- А для submitter отношение один к одному?
- metaDataMap:{} - это поле JSONField?

На всякий случай примеры моделей:
Модель Metadata:

```
export class Metadata {
  url: string;
  name: string;
  value: any;
  hidden: boolean;
  category: string;
  computed: boolean;
  unit: string;
  nodes: {};
}
```

Модель Submitter:

```
export class Submitter {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  institution: string;
}
```